# Using Custom Asserts in Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, domain-driven-design

I asked a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/355831/222996) on here earlier and Laiv shared the following [link](http://www.gridshore.nl/2009/07/29/domain-driven-design-and-the-equals-method/).

In the article; it is stated that Eric Evans avoids `.equals` methods on Entities.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180044/should-one-override-equals-method-for-asserting-the-object-equality-in-a-unit-te); the accepted answerer talks about using Custom Assertions for Unit Testing rather than `.equals`

Therefore I am looking at custom assertions.  I have created the following class, which compares two products:

```
public static bool IsSameDescription(Product product1, Product product2)
        {
            // Check for null values and compare run-time types.
            if (product1 == null || product2==null)
                return false;

            return (product1.description == product2.description);
        }
```

Therefore I can do this in the Unit Test:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expectedProduct, actualProduct);
```

What is I wanted to compare two lists of products? I could use a .equals method and then do this:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedProductList, actualProductList);
```

How would I implement this? I could implement a static function that accepts two lists and compares them.  However, CollectionAssert would not use it? Would it? (because it uses .equals behind the scenes) How can I do this?

Comment: Doesn't the API has something like `Assert.isTrue()`? For instance `Assert.isTrue(IsSameDescription(productA, productB))`

Comment: On the other hand, correct me if I'm worng, looks like you are only concerned about equality because the Unit testing. This's what my link would catalog as *intention* and that's why your link advocates for custom assertions. How to implement custom assertions is implementation details. You should look at the Assert API and do use of all its possibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To apply the same method to a collection, you can use LINQ to great effect.

If you want to compare everything to the same instance you can do this:

```
productList.Select(item => IsSameDescription(productA, item)).ToList();
```

The `CollectionAssert` also has a variant that takes a [comparator function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243753.aspx):

```
CollectionAssert(expectedProductList, actualProductList, IsSameDescription);
```

---

Clarification about custom exceptions:

The primary reason to use custom assertions rather than the generic `AssertTrue` or `Assert.IsTrue` is that the error messages provide more detail as to what exactly the problem was.  For example, `Assert.AreEqual(obj1, obj2)` or `Assert.That(obj1).IsEqualTo(obj2)` will tell you both what the expected answer was and what the actual value was.  That should be the goal you are looking for with any custom assertion.

There are several assertion libraries, so you might have to re-invent the wheel.  Some test libraries have the assertion library included (Like NUnit, JUnit, etc.).

I would much rather see intelligent use of a standard assertion library than writing custom assertions for everything.  Using the example you provided:

```
Assert.AreEqual(product1.Description, product2.Description);
```

Is as expressive as you need.

Comment: What is myCollection? What is product? What is Item? Sorry I don't really understand this.

Comment: I'm using the variable names you defined.  I changed `myCollection` to your example.  `item` is the iterated entry alias.  Read up on LINQ and lambda expressions for more information.

Comment: Be careful with the linq implementation. You have to be sure to actually materialize the query or you'll get wonky results. CollectionAssert with the comparator is much more reliable.

Comment: Correct.  If you call `ToList()` after the select statement to force the LINQ to iterate over the contents it will do it's job.  I'll modify the answer to include that.  Do note that the two statements are testing different things.  The LINQ statement is testing all elements of a collection to a constant product.  The `CollectionAssert` with comparator option is testing two collections against each other.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.com/documentation.html#collections-and-dictionaries) library have nice bunch of assertion methods and possibility to configure them in readable manner.

In your particular case `ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo` method can be used

```
var expectedProducts = new[]
{
    new Product { Id = 1, Description = "One" },
    new Product { Id = 2, Description = "Two" }
}

var actualProducts = classUnderTest.CreateProducts();

actualProducts.ShouldAllBeEquivalent(
     expectedProducts, 
     config => config.Including(product => product.Description));
```

`ShouldAllBeEquivalent` will assert that `actual` collection contains same products as `expected` collection, where equality will be asserted by only `Description` property.